# java.lang.IllegalStateException: RpcEnv already stopped

Tags: scala, apache-spark, datastax

How can we handle below warning message in spark  - 1.6.2. Can someone help on this.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: RpcEnv already stopped
```

> WARN  2018-03-08 07:20:37,049 org.apache.spark.rpc.netty. Dispatcher:
>   Message
>   RemoteProcessDisconnected(prdshsvcs-cassandra-cluster-002:60090)
>   dropped. java.lang.IllegalStateException: RpcEnv already stopped.

Thanks,
Chandra

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: When does this happen? It could be due to message queue being full or  an executor killed.